# PHP - foreach repeating values in every new created array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looping in an `array` and trying to get and push each `element` in another array with `associative key`. then push it again in another array that serves as a `Row` array. The loop shouldn't push the previous `element` on the next `Row` array. But it keeps repeating till the end of the loop

Output that I am getting.

```
Array
(
    [Row1] => Array
        (
            [Container1] => Container is empty at row 1
        )

    [Row2] => Array
        (
            [Container1] => Container is empty at row 1
            [Container2] => Container is empty at row 2
        )

    [Row4] => Array
        (
            [Container1] => Container is empty at row 1
            [Container2] => Container is empty at row 2
            [Container4] => Container is empty at row 4
        )

    [Row5] => Array
        (
            [Container1] => Container is empty at row 1
            [Container2] => Container is empty at row 2
            [Container4] => Container is empty at row 4
            [Container5] => Container is empty at row 5
        )

    [Row6] => Array
        (
            [Container1] => Container is empty at row 1
            [Container2] => Container is empty at row 2
            [Container4] => Container is empty at row 4
            [Container5] => Container is empty at row 5
            [Container6] => Container is empty at row 6
        )
```

The output that I need to.

```
Array
    (
        [Row1] => Array
            (
                [Container1] => Container is empty at row 1
            )

        [Row2] => Array
            (
                [Container2] => Container is empty at row 2
            )

        [Row4] => Array
            (
                [Container4] => Container is empty at row 4
            )

        [Row5] => Array
            (
                [Container5] => Container is empty at row 5
            )

        [Row6] => Array
            (
                [Container6] => Container is empty at row 6
            )
```

Below is my for loop

```
<?php

$errorArray = array();
$ContainerError = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < count($namedDataArray); $i++) { 
    if ($namedDataArray[$i][1] == ''){
        echo '<pre>';
        $ContainerError['Container'.$i] = 'Container is empty at row '. $i;
        echo '</pre>';
        $errorArray['Row'.$i] = $ContainerError;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it by initializing again `$ContainerError = array();` at the end of `if statement`

Answer (score 1):

You could re-initialize `$ContainerError` at the very end of each loop as you did and it'll work fine.
Another way to go, a little bit more efficient if the loop is big enough, is to initialize the array once before entering the loop and then unsetting it at the end of each loop with `unset($ContainerError);`

The effect is exactly the same, but in the past I've found this to shave a second or two of execution time when the loop goes into the tens of thousands of iterations

Comment: I'll take note for that unsetting array for better execution time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple and easy solution, you don't need `$ContainerError`:

```
<?php
array_walk($namedDataArray, function($row,$index) use (&$errorArray){
    static $i=0; // You can use $index instead of $i
    $errorArray['Row'.$i]['Container'.$i] = 'Container is empty at row '. $i++;
});
```

## Test:

```
<?php

$errorArray = array();
$ContainerError = array();


$namedDataArray = range(0, 6);

array_walk($namedDataArray, function() use (&$errorArray){
    static $i=0;
    $errorArray['Row'.$i]['Container'.$i] = 'Container is empty at row '. $i++;
});


print_r( $errorArray );
```

Shows:

```
Array
(
    [Row0] => Array
        (
            [Container0] => Container is empty at row 
        )

    [Row1] => Array
        (
            [Container1] => Container is empty at row 1
        )

    [Row2] => Array
        (
            [Container2] => Container is empty at row 2
        )

    [Row3] => Array
        (
            [Container3] => Container is empty at row 3
        )

    [Row4] => Array
        (
            [Container4] => Container is empty at row 4
        )

    [Row5] => Array
        (
            [Container5] => Container is empty at row 5
        )

    [Row6] => Array
        (
            [Container6] => Container is empty at row 6
        )

)
```

Comment: Good to know about `array_walk` function. I'll try this in my future projects. Thanks!